# Is there a MultiKeyDictionary in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to have a an inventory system in which items can be referenced by name or by their id. I saw somewhere that there is the ability in C# to have a MultiKeyDictionary, but I'm not sure Unity's MonoDevelop has that functionality. Could someone clarify?

I am simply trying to ask if a construct that is essentially a dictionary with multiple keys to one value exists already in Unity. I am not looking to take other's code, I am just asking if this exists or if I would need to write the functionality myself.

Comment: https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MultiKeyDictionary

Comment: Does not exist in the current context. Yes I am using the correct namespaces. Please add something constructive, other than just a link.

Comment: Did you download the source for it or just try to use it?

Comment: I was under the assumption that a MultiKeyDictionary was a built-in type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this type of `Dictionary<object, string>` to simulate multiple keys for same value:

```
        Dictionary<object, string> dico = new Dictionary<object, string>();

        dico.Add(0, "I0");
        dico.Add("Item0", "I0");

        var a = dico[0];
        var b = dico["Item0"];
        // a equal b
```